# Recaptcha in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, recaptcha-v3

I want to get a google token in my flutter mobile application to send to a c# api.

I have this code in the head of `web/index.html`:

```
<head>
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="edesemovilflutter1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>edesemovilflutter1</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LfmjfUlAAAAALWfTxk4PM-SZz7ZLW0575P7WRz1"></script>
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

I have this in my `main.dart`:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    bool ready = await GRecaptchaV3.ready(
        "6LfmjfUlAAAAAF0dxFR_6L4BerFoRLEA3iCDxhlI",
        showBadge: true); //--2
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print("Is Recaptcha ready? $ready");
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ProviderOficinaVirtual(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: '/',
          '/': (BuildContext context) => RecaptchaPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have this in my `RecaptchaPage`:

```
class RecaptchaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecaptchaPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RecaptchaPage> createState() => _RecaptchaPageState();
}

class _RecaptchaPageState extends State<RecaptchaPage> {
  String _token = 'Click the below button to generate token';
  bool badgeVisible = true;
  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> getToken() async {
    String token = await GRecaptchaV3.execute('submit') ?? 'null returned';
    setState(() {
      _token = token;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Recaptcha V3 Web example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SelectableText('Token: $_token\n'),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: getToken,
                child: const Text('Get new token'),
              ),
              OutlinedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (badgeVisible) {
                    GRecaptchaV3.hideBadge();
                  } else {
                    GRecaptchaV3.showBadge();
                  }
                  badgeVisible = !badgeVisible;
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.legend_toggle),
                label: const Text("Toggle Badge Visibilty"),
              ),
              TextButton.icon(
                  label: const Icon(Icons.copy),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Clipboard.setData(const ClipboardData(
                        text: "https://pub.dev/packages/g_recaptcha_v3"));
                  },
                  icon: const SelectableText(
                      "https://pub.dev/packages/g_recaptcha_v3")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The _token variable only get the value 'null returned', how can I resolve it?

I want to get a Google token to send it to an api.

These are my keys:

[image]